# Prevent Oracle Connection autocommit for JNDI Datasource on JBoss 7 (Jeeves DBMS)

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, datasource, autocommit

I am currently having an odd situation with the autocommit settings of an Oracle JNDI Datasource in JBoss 7.

**The outline**

The application I want to deploy, wich I can inspect but not change, obtains connections from the Connection Pool and trys to commit after certain statements. Obviously the connection has autocommit set to 'true' per default and so an exception is raised.

```
    You cannot commit with autocommit set!
```

**What I cannot do**

Due to the fact that I can't change the application source, the following "solution" is not applicable:

```
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

**What I tried**

I looked through the XML Schema of the standalone.xml and found two promising elements in the datasource definition:

```
    <connection-property name="autoCommit">
     false
    </connection-property>
```

but this is being ignored.

Further I tried using a xa-datasource with the following property:

```
    <xa-datasource-property name="autoCommit">
     false
    </xa-datasource-property>
```

but the autoCommit property belongs to the connection, not the datasource, so a PropertyNotFound Exception is raised.

**My question**

How can I set Autocommit to false in a JNDI Datasource under JBoss7 and am I missing something?

**My definition**

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/*****" pool-name="*****" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:****:****</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="autoCommit">
        false
    </connection-property>
    <driver>oracle.jdbc</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
        <security>
        <user-name>*****</user-name>
        <password>*****</password>
    </security>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

**Update**

Code Snippet:

```
      public AccessManager(jeeves.resources.dbms.Dbms dbms, SettingManager sm)
        throws SQLException
      {
        List operList = dbms.select("SELECT * FROM Operations").getChildren();          
      }
```

**Update 2**

The Application I want to deploy is the Geonetwork CSW 2.9.0, just in case someone has experience with this. I have to configure a JNDI datasource because the spatial indexing only happens on container managed connections.

**Update 3**

Stacktrace:

```
    15:52:18,203 ERROR [jeeves.engine] (MSC service thread 1-4) Raised exception while starting appl handler. Skipped.
    15:52:18,205 ERROR [jeeves.engine] (MSC service thread 1-4)    Handler   : org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork
    15:52:18,206 ERROR [jeeves.engine] (MSC service thread 1-4)    Exception : java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit with autocommit set!
    15:52:18,210 ERROR [jeeves.engine] (MSC service thread 1-4)    Message   : You cannot commit with autocommit set!
    15:52:18,213 ERROR [jeeves.engine] (MSC service thread 1-4)    Stack     : java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit with autocommit set!
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:984)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:757)
            at jeeves.resources.dbms.Dbms.commit(Dbms.java:150)
            at jeeves.resources.dbms.AbstractDbmsPool.close(AbstractDbmsPool.java:158)
            at jeeves.server.resources.ResourceManager.release(ResourceManager.java:302)
            at jeeves.server.resources.ResourceManager.close(ResourceManager.java:270)
            at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.initAppHandler(JeevesEngine.java:556)
            at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.init(JeevesEngine.java:182)
            at jeeves.server.sources.http.JeevesServlet.init(JeevesServlet.java:87)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Update 4**

Just realized that the Jeeves DBMS is a simple wrapper around the JNDI Datasource that obtains connections just like anyone would do with plain JDBC. So I am back at the beginning.

Comment: Quick test: try setting JTA to true, because that should force autocommit to be false by default. The deal here is that your question is asked from the wrong perspective; datasources don't manage the autocommit settings of connections, that is the responsibility of the logic that wants to use a connection. So what technology is using the datasource to obtain connections? The answer should be there.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this actually made me think a bit further. I just realized that the technology used is Jeeves DBMS (don't know if you can call it that, I have no experience with jeeves) Unfortunately JTA=true does not work either. (Updated Question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for giving me directions, found a solution (**Correction:** Workaround) that suits me well. I made a wrapper around the original datasource, overrid the getConnection() Method and bound it under a new JNDI Name. This way I have full control over the datasource without losing any functionality from the container.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is an actual solution or only a workaround, but if you determine you're helped because of it (for now) - I won't give it any further though.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is not a real solution. It is a "crafted solution", but not in the common stackoverflow sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JSniffer I am also facing same issue.. could you please provide all details what you change?